# Fetch Z random items from array of size N in Z time?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, underscore.js

I've got an array of size N which might be ordered in a certain way. I would like to get Z random items from this array in < O(N) time.

My understanding is that if I shuffle my array using Underscore's _.shuffle() that will take O(N) time. So, shuffling and then grabbing the 1st Z items is out.

If I generate Z random numbers between N, I think I can get into really ugly worst-case scenarios. This is because if N is something like 105 and Z is 100.. well, there will be a lot of overlap and maybe I'll reroll Z several hundred times.

I was wondering if there was a simple solution to this issue? I didn't see any Underscore methods specifically up to the task.

Comment: what does "< O(N) time" actually mean?  O(logN) ???  "if N is something like 105 and Z is 100" then O(Z) is O(N) ....

Comment: I am only worried about sufficiently large cases of N. Z will be constrained to a sufficiently large sample size. For this example, lets say Z can be no larger than 300, but N is no larger than 30,000. I'd prefer if the solution did not scale with the size of N, but O(logN) would indeed be less than O(N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm don't think I fully understand your problem, but if you want to get a random element from an array and for it not to be repeated and hence you are limited to rolling fewer times than there are elements, then you can try this

```js
function shuffle(obj, rounds, deep) {
  var length = obj.length;
  if (length < 2) {
    return;
  }

  var rounds32 = rounds >>> 0 || 1;
  var deepBool = deep === true;
  var roundCount = 0;
  var index, rnd, tmp;
  while (roundCount < rounds32) {
    index = length;
    while (index) {
      if (Array.isArray(obj[index - 1])) {
        shuffle(obj[i], rounds32, deepBool);
      }

      rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * index);
      index -= 1;
      tmp = obj[index];
      obj[index] = obj[rnd];
      obj[rnd] = tmp;
    }

    roundCount += 1;
  }
}

var array = [];
for (var count = 0; count < 100; count += 1) {
  array.push(count);
}

shuffle(array);

var rolls = 10;
console.log(array.slice(0, rolls));
```

Comment: Thanks! The second one is super easy for me to understand and about what I was thinking. :) Appreciate it.

Comment: Be careful with implementing your own shuffle algorithms, you have to prove that it will generate a uniformly random permutation. See the link http://www.cigital.com/papers/download/developer_gambling.php

Comment: If you look, then you will notice a Fisher–Yates algorithm at the heart of it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few algorithms to consider:

**A. Shuffle**

1. Shuffle array ; O(N)
2. Pick first Z items ; O(Z) or better

Overall complexity: O(N)

```
function A(array, z) {
  return _.first(_.shuffle(array), z);
}
```

**B. Random Selection with Re-rolls**

1. Pick a random number from 0..N-1 ; O(1)
2. If the number has been picked before, go to step 1
3. Record the picked number ; O(1)
4. Pick an item from the array at the given index ; O(1)
5. If we've picked less than Z items, go to step 1

Overall complexity:

For Z << N, O(Z) average case

For Z = N, O(N^2) average case

```
function B(array, z) {
  var pickedIndices = {};
  var result = [];
  while (result.length < z) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    if (!(randomIndex in pickedIndices)) {
      pickedIndices[randomIndex] = 1;
      result.push(array[randomIndex]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

**C. Random Selection with Removal**

1. Make a copy of the array ; O(N)
2. Pick a random item from the array ; O(1)
3. Remove the item from the array ; O(N)
4. If we've picked less than Z items, go to step 2

Overall complexity: O(Z*N)

```
function C(array, z) {
  var result = [];
  array = array.slice(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < z; i++) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    result.push(array.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

**Performance Testing**

http://jsperf.com/fetch-z-random-items-from-array-of-size-n

With N = 100 and Z = 10, algorithm C was the fastest (probably because most of the logic uses native functions and/or is easy to optimize, which for small values of N and Z is more important than the algorithmic complexity).

With N = 100 and Z = 100, algorithm A was the fastest.

With N = 1000 and Z = 100, algorithm B was the fastest.

**Conclusion**

There's no one best algorithm among those I considered; it depends on the characteristics of your data. If the characteristics of your data can vary, it might be worthwhile to do further testing and create some criteria based on the values of N and Z to selectively choose the best algorithm.

For example, if Z <= N/2, you might use algorithm B; otherwise, algorithm A.

In short, there's no "simple" solution that always has great performance.